# using awk to find differences in two files using specific field

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to find the differences between `file1` and `file2` using `$5` as the match criteria. I thought the `awk` would work but as of now it seems to output what is in common between the two files. I also tried reversing the files with the same result. Thank you :).

**awk with current output**

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$5]; next} $5 in a' file1 file2
chr10    102586755   102586862   chr10:102586755-102586862   PAX2-1650|gc=63
chr10    102587289   102587450   chr10:102587289-102587450   PAX2-1651|gc=65

awk 'FNR==NR {a[$5]; next} $5 in a' file2 file1
chr10    102586755   102586862   chr10:102586755-102586862   PAX2-1650|gc=63
chr10    102587289   102587450   chr10:102587289-102587450   PAX2-1651|gc=65
```

**file1**

```
chr10    102586755   102586862   chr10:102586755-102586862   PAX2-1650|gc=63
chr10    102587289   102587450   chr10:102587289-102587450   PAX2-1651|gc=65
chr10    102732659   102732803   chr10:102732659-102732803   unknown-1652|gc=59.4
chr10    102732875   102733044   chr10:102732875-102733044   unknown-1653|gc=61.3
```

**file2**

```
chr10    102586755   102586862   chr10:102586755-102586862   PAX2-1650|gc=63
chr10    102587289   102587450   chr10:102587289-102587450   PAX2-1651|gc=65
chr10    102732659   102732803   chr10:102732659-102732803   C10ORF2-1652|gc=59.4
chr10    102732875   102733044   chr10:102732875-102733044   C10ORF2-1653|gc=61.3
```

**desired output**

```
chr10    102732659   102732803   chr10:102732659-102732803   C10ORF2-1652|gc=59.4
chr10    102732875   102733044   chr10:102732875-102733044   C10ORF2-1653|gc=61.3
```

edit: maybe this `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5];next} !($5 in a)' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to use `!($5 in a)` rather than `$5 in a` as your condition to print:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { a[$5]; next } !($5 in a)' file1 file2
chr10    102732659   102732803   chr10:102732659-102732803   C10ORF2-1652|gc=59.4
chr10    102732875   102733044   chr10:102732875-102733044   C10ORF2-1653|gc=61.3
```